# .php files downloading instead of executing

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am brand new to Apache and PHP.

I created a helloworld.php file and when I run it, the file downloads and the command is never executed.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache 2 and PHP 7.1 .

I tried completely reinstalling everything and also editing the apache2.conf file with this :

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

But this did not work.

I tried installing LAMP from : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

But during the last step, I created an info.php file with these lines of code :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And the above lines were displayed as it is.

I tried finding the solution, but most of them mention a httpd.conf file, which I am not able to find anywhere.

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but I didn't find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Are you sure php is installed ?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have checked it.

Comment: do you have an /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.* set of files ? if yes, you have to a2enmod php7 (on Debian, not certain about Ubuntu).

Comment: so where did you put this php file you created ? You have to put it in www directory.

Comment: mind telling us how you're accessing those files? Are you doing `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php` directly in the browser? @HarshBhardwaj

Comment: Did you also follow http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php ?

Comment: for the info.php I mentioned above, I used http://localhost/file.php.

Comment: In your apache php is not activated. Please reinstall apache and then php. Or simply go to the conf file of apache and configure php correctly.

Comment: Check out the changes to the conf file in this article: http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html

Comment: seems like you have not enabled `mod_php` in your apache. Try running the command `sudo a2enmod php7.0` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like apache PHP module is not installed. First of all install apache php module from following command:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

And then enable the module with following command:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```